# VB.Net - Program Soft Locks When Removing a User from All AD Groups

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, account-management

I'm writing an application in VB.Net which accepts an AD account input by the user and deprovisions and disables it automatically. As part of this, it strips all AD groups it can from the user.

Note that certain users may be members of groups that the person running the program does not have permission to modify, and that's OK for my requirements. These groups do not have a standard naming convention or format.

The following code removes the user from all groups they are a member of successfully, skipping any groups the person operating the program does not have permission to modify, but the catch is the program then appears to soft lock after attempting to remove a group it cannot (such as Domain Users)! What can I do to prevent this?

```
Dim ctx As DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext = New DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain, "net.mydomain.co.uk")
Dim user As DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal = DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, tbxUsertoDeprovision.Text)
For Each group As DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal In user.GetGroups(ctx)
    Try
        group.Members.Remove(user)
        group.Save()
        group.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Continue For
    End Try
Next
```

If I insert a Message Box into the Catch as follows:

```
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    Continue For
```

Then run the code, it displays the following message box, but only once:

System.InvalidOperation.Exception: The member can not be removed from the Group object's Members property because it has this group as its primary group. (This is at the `group.Members.Remove(user)` line).

The program then goes no further and no code after `Next` is ever executed. I'm forced to close the application.

Comment: Note that I have tried removing the `Continue For` line, the behaviour seems to be the same, with or without that present.

Comment: In the politest way, that is not how exceptions are supposed to be used. I would suggest learning how to use try..catch..end try, but for the moment run the code without and exception handling so that your program does crash and visual studio can show you what the error is.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning EVERYTHING let alone Try Catch! Very much experimenting and learning as I go with this project of mine. I'll remove the Try early this afternoon and run a couple of tests to see what exception it actually throws.

Comment: Ok here's what I get:

System.InvalidOperation.Exception: The member can not be removed from the Group object's Members property because it has this group as its primary group.

It's failing at the following line specifically: `group.Members.Remove(user)`

Comment: Which is expected, and I'm fully aware the group cannot be removed, but I want it to skip that group and keep going to remove any other groups it can, before exiting the For statement.

Comment: Also, quite interestingly, if I put the Try Catch back in and make the Catch output `ex.ToString()` in a Message Box, the message box only displays once. So maybe it isn't looping it's just... stopping altogether?

Comment: I would suggest now that you add the error information into your question. Sadly I don't know enough about active directory.